# Для чего некоторые слова в тексте заключают в квадратные скобки?

Tags: пунктуация

Вот, например, цитата из книги Дао Дэ Цзин:

> Дао — глубокая [основа] всех вещей.

Я встречал подобное обозначение и в Библии, и, кажется, в художественной литературе, но, к сожалению, не могу сейчас найти дополнительные примеры.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Это означает, что слово восстановлено по контексту, но в оригинале не присутствует. Такое часто можно встретить в переводах, где язык оригинала позволяет опускать слово, без которого перевод невозможен, в восстановленных документах, где некоторые слова утеряны, при цитировании фраз, вырванных из контекста.